# Calling a perl script from my bash script: Perl script won't follow symbolic links

Tags: bash, shell-script, perl, symlink

There is a perl script, which for various reasons I cannot change, which does things.

When I use it from the terminal, it works perfectly on regular files and symlinks:

```
$ perl_script file_to_use
```

I am trying to call that perl script from the bash script I am working on, using the normal terminal nomenclature: (this is currently the whole script)

```
    #!/bin/bash
    perl_script file_to_use;
```

---

Unfortunately, when the file_to_use is a symlink, when using it from inside the bash script, it comes back as file not found (the basic code which causes it)

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    ...
    $file_to_use = $ARGV[0];
    if (! -e "/some/dir/$file_to_use") {
    print "File not found\n";
    exit;
    }
    ...
```

---

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: `-e` works on symbolic links. Check that your files do not have DOS-style CRLF line endings so that perl thinks $file_to_use is `"file_to_use\r"`

Comment: Let me edit a bit for clarity - the perl script works fine from the terminal, just not when called from my bash script.

Comment: @solenoid: please reduce your bash script to only call the command and do nothing else - i.e. everything you do in the terminal but nothing more.  This should work. Then slowly add the stuff around it you have currently because it is likely this stuff you don't show which causes the actual problem.

Comment: @solenoid, I understand that: try `od -c bash.script` and look for `\r` characters

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I actually did this - the only line are the ones in my example and it doesnt work (I should take out the ellipses).

Comment: @glennjackman 0 occurrences.

Comment: Your `/some/dir`, are your sure it's an absolute path ?

Comment: @Philippe yes. the perl script has been in production for a while. It actually prints out the file path on the failure, /some/dir/$file_to_use, and it is the right path (I copied the printed output, and just straight up did $ vi <paste> and it went to edit the file correctly.

Comment: `pathlld` might help. https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld